# Error defining delete task

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am getting errors with the following block of DSL script.

```
val DerbyDbDataFolder: File = file("DerbyDbData")
val DerbyLog: File = file("derby.log")

tasks {
    var cleanDerbyDbData by creating (Delete::class) {
        delete(DerbyDbDataFolder)
        delete(DerbyLog)
    }

    "clean" {
        dependsOn(cleanDerbyDbData)
    }
}
```

But I get the following error message.

```
       var cleanDerbyDbData by creating (Delete::class) {
                               ^ Missing 'setValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>, Delete)' method on delegate of type 'PolymorphicDomainObjectContainer<Delete>'
```

What is this error message and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR

Define `cleanDerbyDbData` as a `val` instead of `var`:

```
val DerbyDbDataFolder: File = file("DerbyDbData")
val DerbyLog: File = file("derby.log")

tasks {
    val cleanDerbyDbData by creating (Delete::class) {
        delete(DerbyDbDataFolder)
        delete(DerbyLog)
    }

    "clean" {
        dependsOn(cleanDerbyDbData)
    }
}
```

### Details

`cleanDerbyDbData` is a [delegated property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html), and for it to be a `var`, the expression to the right of `by` must return a mutable value. The [PolymorphicDomainObjectContainerDelegateProvider](https://gradle.github.io/gradle-script-kotlin-docs/api/org.gradle.script.lang.kotlin/-polymorphic-domain-object-container-delegate-provider/index.html) returned by the `creating()` function doesn't provide any setters, and this is the error you're seeing.